# Can not access the web with Chrome

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl

We have just setup a web site , IE and firefox works fine to access it , but when use Chrome , the https is not works , it pops the below error , would advise how can I fix it ? thanks

```
mysite.com

identity not verified.

the identity of this website has been verified by geo trust ssl CA but     does not have public audit records.

the site is using outdate security setting that may prevent future version of Chrome from being able to safely access it.


Your connection to mysite.com is encrypted with obsolete cryptography.

the connection uses TLS 1.2.

the connection is encrypted using RC4_128 with SHA1 for message authentication and RSA as the key exchange mechanism.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Obsolete cryptography warning from Browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30270788/obsolete-cryptography-warning-from-browser). Also see [Google Chrome “Your connection to website is encrypted with obsolete cryptography”](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/83831) and [Chrome showing cryptography as 'obsolete'](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/85532).

Answer (score 1):

If you see an SSL error message in Chrome saying "Your connection is not private," it means your Internet connection, or your computer, is stopping Chrome from loading the page securely.

If you are a web user and you see this warning, you can contact the site owner to make sure that they are aware of the warning. The site is no less secure today than it was last month, but Google is starting to bring awareness to the less secure SHA-1 signed certificates.

> The certificate is unable to be audited. In other words, it does not
>   have the necessary information to be able to go to the CA and check if
>   the certificate has been manually revoked prior to its expiration.

HTTPS sites whose certificate chains use SHA-1 and are valid past 1 January 2017 will no longer appear to be fully trustworthy in Chrome's user interface.

References :

Check connection to a website [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95617?hl=en).

Sunsetting SHA-1 -  [blog](http://blog.chromium.org/2014/09/gradually-sunsetting-sha-1.html)

Also more at [security.exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/63390/i-see-a-warning-notification-site-not-verified)

Comment: thanks reply , is it means we are using SHA-1 , it will no longer be suport after 1 January 2017 ? what I have to do is upgrade it ? thanks

Comment: you can mark answer if it was helpful..thanks..check your connection through that links in reference as well.