# Your Connection is not private error after installing SSL Certificate on Xampp Apache

Tags: php, apache, ssl, xampp, ssl-certificate

Kindly help me i have installed (CA Authorized) SSL certificate on my company Xampp Apache Windows 2012 R2 Server. I suppose everything is configured correctly regrading SSL certificate.

Now problem i am facing is when i try to access the website on web server with https in front of sever IP. it is giving me "Your connection is not Private" Error.

Certificate is issued on name of company website (www.balah.com) and dns is not yet added in domain panel.

So i trying to access it using Https: in front of IP.
Kindly help.

Comment: Check the specific error name there, like NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Comment: Are you using SHA1 past the 1st of Jan 2017 for your certificate ? Chrome doesn't like it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29787365/can-not-access-the-web-with-chrome